# How to receive data from multiple WebSockets asynchronously in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio

I am currently trying to use the [websockets library](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). If another library is better suited for this purpose, let me know.

Given these functions:

```
def handle_message(msg):
    # do something

async def consumer_handler(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        handle_message(message)
```

How can I (indefinitely) connect to multiple websockets? Would the below code work?

```
import asyncio
import websockets


connections = set()
connections.add(websockets.connect(consumer_handler, 'wss://api.foo.com', 8765))
connections.add(websockets.connect(consumer_handler, 'wss://api.bar.com', 8765))
connections.add(websockets.connect(consumer_handler, 'wss://api.foobar.com', 8765))

async def handler():
    await asyncio.wait([ws for ws in connections])

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(handler())
```

Answer (score 9):

For anyone who finds this, I found an answer. Only works in > Python 3.6.1 I believe.

```
import asyncio
import websockets

connections = set()
connections.add('wss://api.foo.com:8765')
connections.add('wss://api.bar.com:8765'))
connections.add('wss://api.foobar.com:8765'))

async def handle_socket(uri, ):
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        async for message in websocket:
            print(message)

async def handler():
    await asyncio.wait([handle_socket(uri) for uri in connections])

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(handler())
```

Comment: I was looking something similar with auto connect feature to ensure that the clients are always connected to the websocket Server. If the connection was closed I want the clients to re-establish the connection with the servers. For example `wss://api.foobar.com:8765` websocket server was restarted. The client should reconnects automatically after few intervals. Can you help illustrate how to write such functionalities?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
connections = set()
```

I would list it:

```
connections = []
connections = ["wss://api.foo.com:8765"]
connections.append ("wss://api.bar.com:8765")
connections.append ("wss://api.foobar.com:8765")
```